# Converting/Re-Writing Paper in LaTeX from Word

Tags: msword, write

I have a paper that I wrote in Word with accompanied math equations (for my undergraduate level research paper for mathematics degree) and I just am not at all familiar with LaTeX. I was wondering what resources I could use to get this paper re-written into LaTeX. I will never need to use the program again, so I was really looking for someone who could convert it for me. I would be interested in paying.

If hiring somebody for this isn't an option, could someone maybe help me write it? This program seems like a lot of work where I only have 4 days to get it re-written.

Comment: http://tug.org/consultants.html